# El phpMyAdmin de XAMPP me exporta las DB vacías

Tags: xampp

Mi XAMPP me está dando algunos disgustos últimamente. Hace tiempo se me desconfiguró (no sé muy bien por qué), y no se llegaba a conectar, intenté reconfigurar los puertos pero no se ejecutaba así que al final, perdí el proyecto con el que estaba trabajando y lo volví a instalar de nuevas.

Parecía que todo funcionaba ok y he estado trabajando correctamente en una web en WordPress en mi localhost, hasta que tuve que exportar la DB asociada a ese proyecto y se exporta vacía (un archivo .sql en mi escritorio que pesa 0kb, no tiene información). La exportación la hago desde XAMPP, pincho en Admin para abrir PHPMyAdmin, y desde ahí hago el proceso normal de exportación de un DB (seleccionar, dar a exportar y descargar el SQL).

Actualmente, XAMPP se ejecuta con un error:

> Tomcat not found, Disabling Tomcat buttons, Run this program from your XAMPP root directory!

(adjunto pantallazo)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Qué puede estar pasando?

Comment: HOla, bienvenidx a SOes. Por favor, incluye en la pregunta algo de info sobre tu xampp que permita a los demás hacer algo aparte de _adivinar_. Cómo exportas las BD? Cómo está configurado xampp? El error que refieres no tiene relación alguna con la BD en xampp. Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante a forma de [Ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta)

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Puede que esté relacionado a [esta pregunta](/q/533069/). En este caso, Tomcat no incide en el problema.